# How can I get stackoverflow data for experimentation?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

I need Stack Overflow data for performing some experimentation about deciding answer quality. How can I get data ?

Comment: You mean like [this](http://data.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: I really don't have an answer for this. But I'm curious as to what experimentation you will be doing

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [Stak Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/).

On the [Compose Query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new) page, you'll find documentation and table layouts so you can retrieve your desired data.

You can also search to make sure the data query you plan on performing hasn't already been done (if it's a simple query, it's probably been done before).

Answer (score 2):

If the online data explorer isn't enough or you need the data in a different format, you can grab the [data dump](http://www.clearbits.net/creators/146-stack-exchange-data-dump) and process it as you wish